# Trouble Upgrading via Command Line

Tags: upgrades

When I attempt to upgrade Craft from 3.5.14 to 3.7 or 4 via the command line (`php craft update` or `php craft update all`) on my local test machine, I get a number of errors ending in a fatal error:

`PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught yii\base\ErrorException: Return type of yii\caching\Cache::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Volumes/.../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/Cache.php:523`

I'm not sure how to debug this issue. Should I try a fresh install? If so, can I install straight to 3.7.27.2 on my exiting test site?

Any help would be much appreciated.